# Google Youtube API v3 Playlist title new

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to port a application developed using version 2 API of google youtube to version 3.

How can I get title of a playlist using version 3 API? We could get the title of playlist using version 2. However, title I get when I query playlist's snippet is different from what it is shown on the youtube website.

Is there any difference in Version 3?

I am using .NET API library from Google. if this helps.

Can anyone please help?

I tried using Version 3 API from Google and when I am trying to get playlists using

var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("snippet,contentDetails");

after setting channelsListRequest.ForUserName, i call var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

From the response, I would then get the playlist list sent using:

```
foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
        {
            var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;
            var nextPageToken = "";
            while (nextPageToken != null)
            {
                var playlistRequest = youtubeService.Playlists.List("id,snippet,contentDetails,status,player");
                playlistRequest.Id = uploadsListId;
                playlistRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                playlistRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;
                var playlistListResponse = await playlistRequest.ExecuteAsync();
                if (playlistListResponse.Items.Count > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show(playlistListResponse.Items[0].Snippet.Title);
            }

        }
```

The messagebox displays the comment that was added when creating playlist. However, when I view in youtube using a browser, the playlist title is displayed properly.